# Video closes after playing

Tags: ios, objective-c, video

Is it possible to make the video not close after it has finished playing? So this would allow the user to press "done" when the video is finished and then the video will close.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>


@interface player1: UIViewController {
}

-(IBAction) playMovie;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation player1

-(IBAction) playMovie {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2.DragtoopenfileinaVM" ofType:@"mp4"]];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *windowsmac = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:windowsmac];

    windowsmac.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    [windowsmac.moviePlayer play];

    windowsmac = nil;   

}
```

This is the coding I'm using, could someone help?

Comment: What you wants to acheive here in unClear.

Comment: i want the video when played to not close, i want the user to press done (top left of video) to close the video.

Comment: Video will automatically play until it completes it duration Or done pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:moviePlayer

                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification

                                              object:moviePlayer.moviePlayer];

 [self presentViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand what I need to remove. Do I remove "MPMoviePlayerViewController *windowsmac = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
"

Comment: Remove line  
windowsmac = nil; 
than past my code 
All wiil be fine.

Comment: Hey, have edit my Answer, its working fine for me . Just try this .